# How to take reCaptcha image in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, recaptcha, captcha

When I try to get `reCaptcha v2` image in selenium, I get `no such this element` because the element not in the main page

so how can I get the picture in selenium C#!

```
  _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo");

            _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);

            _driver.FindElement(By.Id("recaptcha-anchor")).Click();



            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);

            //To get all images in page
            IList<IWebElement> images = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("img"));

            MessageBox.Show(images.Count.ToString());

            string reCaptchaXpath = "";

            foreach (var img in images)
            {
                if (img.GetAttribute("src").Contains("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/"))
                {
                    reCaptchaXpath = GenerateXpath(img, "");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit-1**

Below code works fine for me and gives 16 images

```
        ChromeDriver _driver;
        _driver = new ChromeDriver();
        _driver.Url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo";
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe[src*='recaptcha']")));

        _driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark")).Click();

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        //_driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe[src*='recaptcha']")));

        _driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
        _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"))[1]);
        images = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("img"));

        Console.WriteLine(images.Count.ToString());
```

**Original Answer**

Your issue is the below statement

```
_driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
```

You are assuming there is just one frame. But there are multiple frames

[image: IFrames]

You need to use

```
_driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_driver.FindElement(By.Css("iframe[src*='recaptcha']")));
```

Comment: Not work 

Error :
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"iframe[src*='recaptcha']"}

Also, same error when I use CssSelector

Comment: Why are you using method tag name? Show the error using css?

Comment: I don't see Css in selenium C#
CssSelector but its same problem